# Django ORM query helps~~~

Tags: django, django-models

I want to filter a class by providing a list

```
first_name = ['John', 'Lian']
employees = Employee.objects.filter(firstname in first_name)
```

In real case, the first_name is generated on the fly.

And now I received that `'global name 'firstname' is not defined'` error. 
I'm sure that there's a field in Employee class called firstname.

How can I fix this?
Thanks for your help!

Model class

```
class Employee(models.Model):

    status= fields.BooleanField(default=True)
    title = fields.CharField(max_length=128)
    first_name = models.ManyToManyField('First_name', blank=True, null=True)
```

Notice: This isn't real model but can represent this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the next line:

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(firstname__in = first_name)
```

If first_name field is ManyToManyField (and First_name model contains field "name"), you should try something like this:

```
first_names = ['John', 'Lian']
employees = Employee.objects.filter(first_name__title__in = first_names)
```

Another way:

```
first_names = ['John', 'Lian']
instances = [First_name.objects.get(title = title) for title in first_names]
employees = Employee.objects.filter(first_name__in = instances)
```

Comment: And it says 'int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'

Comment: I'm using title attribute, but still got ''ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'title''

Comment: Well, there's one more way to do that.

Comment: @user469652, the reason you're getting `'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'title'`  is because you are copy and pasting. You never told us what the fields are in the related `m2m` model, so ikostia is just using sample code.If you don't have a field called `title` in your `First_name` model, you're going to have to adapt it to fit your field names. The answer is correct. Adapt #2 and #3 to your model and you have your answer.

Comment: @Yuji, I didn't do copy and paste, the example code is taken from real model.